# how to solve this error weka.core.UnassignedDatasetException: Instance doesn't have access to a dataset

Tags: java, instance, weka

the Instance that I create does not enter the training module what should I do?

```
public static int classify(int Newlength,int count7, int count8,int count2,int count6,int count3,int count1,int count4, int count5,boolean Backslash,boolean if_https, boolean if_http,boolean ifIP) {            
 // Create attributes to be used with classifiers

    int result = -1;
    try {

        ArrayList<Attribute> attributeList = new ArrayList<Attribute>();

        Attribute length = new Attribute("length");
        Attribute hashtag = new Attribute("#");
        Attribute percentage = new Attribute("%");
        Attribute at = new Attribute("@");
        Attribute qustionmark = new Attribute("?");
        Attribute and = new Attribute("&");
        Attribute singdoller = new Attribute("$");
        Attribute dot = new Attribute(".");
        Attribute colon = new Attribute(":");//  its mean :
        Attribute doublebackshalsh = new Attribute("//");
        Attribute https = new Attribute("https");
        Attribute http = new Attribute("http");
        Attribute ip = new Attribute("Ip");

        ArrayList<String> classVal = new ArrayList<String>();
        classVal.add("YES");
        classVal.add("NO");


        attributeList.add(length);
        attributeList.add(hashtag);
        attributeList.add(percentage);
        attributeList.add(at);
        attributeList.add(qustionmark);
        attributeList.add(and);
        attributeList.add(singdoller);
        attributeList.add(dot);
        attributeList.add(colon);
        attributeList.add(doublebackshalsh);
        attributeList.add(https);
        attributeList.add(http);
        attributeList.add(ip);

       attributeList.add(new Attribute("@@Target@",classVal));


      Instances data = new Instances("TestInstances",attributeList,0);
        System.out.println(data);

        Instance inst_co = new DenseInstance(data.numAttributes());
        data.add(inst_co);


       String bs=Boolean.toString(Backslash);//for backslash
       String hs=Boolean.toString(if_https);//for https
       String hp=Boolean.toString(if_http);//for http
       String ips=Boolean.toString(ifIP);// for ip


        inst_co.setValue(length,Newlength);
        inst_co.setValue(hashtag,count7);
        inst_co.setValue(percentage,count8);
        inst_co.setValue(at,count2);
        inst_co.setValue(qustionmark, count6);
        inst_co.setValue(and, count3);
        inst_co.setValue(singdoller,count1);
        inst_co.setValue(dot,count4);
        inst_co.setValue(colon,count5);
        inst_co.setValue(doublebackshalsh,2);
        inst_co.setValue(https,3);
        inst_co.setValue(http, 5);
        inst_co.setValue(ip, 3);
        System.out.println("The instance: " + inst_co); 
    //    inst_co.setDataset(race);  

        // load classifier from file
        Classifier cls_co = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper
                .read("src/user_withexcel3/FL.model");

        result = (int) cls_co.classifyInstance(inst_co); 
        System.out.println(result);

        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set data set of instance after setting values of instance:

```
inst_co.setValue(ip, 3);
// set dataset
inst_co.setDataset(data);
```